# Can I get PSP DLC onto my Vita?

Tags: ps-vita

I have a couple PSP games (Disgaea 2 and Prinny: Can I really Be The Hero?) where I had DLC on my PSP but the DLC is not available on the PSN for Vita.

Is there some way I can copy the DLC from the PSP onto the Vita sort of like you can with [save files](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-can-i-move-my-psp-game-saves-onto-my-ps-vita)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it via a PS3, if you have one. Just download the DLC to the PS3 and install it to the Vita using the content manager.

Comment: I see now; you have to redownload the content onto the PS3 to copy it over; I already had the content on the PS3 and apparently the old copies expired.