# "The data is corrupted" error when copying save game from PS Vita to PSP 3000

Tags: ps-vita, psp

I would like to record some game play and I have the required cables to do this on the PSP 3000. My problem is that my game saved game file is on a PS Vita and when I try to copy the saved game to my PSP 3000 it tells me that the data is corrupted.

*"Load failed the data is corrupted 80110306"*

I have seen [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-can-i-move-my-psp-game-saves-onto-my-ps-vita) but it is the other way around.

So, can someone help me transferring the saved data from my PS Vita to my PSP 3000 or record the screen from my PS Vita?

Comment: Have you tried transferring via a PC or PS3? That is: Back up the savegame from Vita to PC/PS3, then restoring it from PC/PS3 to PSP 3000?

Comment: I have done it through the PC like this: 1) Turn on the PS Vita And connect the USB Cable. 2) go to the psp folder and copy saved game data to the pc. 3) connect the PSP3000 to the computer. 4) Transfer the saved data to the psp saved game folder... Now I'll get the error when I try to load the saved game file inside the game.

Comment: Also, be aware that PSP is very sensitive to low-grade USB cables. I consistently had problems transferring files to and from my PSP until I spent a few bucks more for a decent cable.